# Pandas Series to_record

Tags: pandas

Wondering how to output a pandas Series to_record or to_dict(orient="record"),
since this is only for dataframe.
The obvious solution would be a for loop, but is there one line way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Is this what you are after?

s.to_frame().to_records()
```